# How to convert a Linux system from a virtualbox machine to a physical machine without losing data?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, iso, bootable, cloning

I need to convert a CentOs 7 from virtualbox to a file .iso and then transfer this .iso file to a usb stick or bootable DVD and install that CentOs (contains my files and packages that I want) to another machines (without virtualbox).

How I can convert vdi to iso? What is the best and deterministic way to do?

Comment: Did you need to duplicate the virtual machine to a physical machine?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to dd to a external disk or if you're not using lvm you can use clonezilla.

**Clonezilla (Only with no LVM):**
1 .- Configure vm --> Put the clonezilla ISO
2 .- Connect a USB drive with enought space to VM
3 .- Make a clone of the virtual machine to the HDD
4 .- Restore that clone into your baremetal machine

**DD .-**
1.- Configure vm --> Put any linux live image
2.- Connect a USB with enough space to VM
3.- Check the device where your USB is connected
4.-

```
dd if=/dev/yourvmdisk of=/path/to/usb/drive/image.iso
```

4.1.- If you connect directly the hard drive of the baremetal machine you can do the dd directly to the hdd:

```
dd if=/dev/yourvmdisk of=/dev/your_baremetal_machine_hdd
```

5.- Go for coffe and wait.
6.- Run a live image on the baremetal machine and connect the usb with the .iso file
6.1.- Put the hdd again in your baremetal machine and run
7.- dd if=/path/to/isofile.iso of=/dev/your_baremetal_hdd_drive

Good luck

Comment: Could you give an example? Does the external disk need to be the same size ?

Comment: Edited and explained

Comment: The external disk needs to have equal or higher capacity than your cloned image

Comment: Clonezilla claims to support LVM2: https://clonezilla.org/